# check or condition in where clause

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I want to check **OR** condition for the variable **role_id** in **role_mapping** table. I want to check if **user_id** has **role_id** either '2' or '3'. User with **user_id=210** has **role_id** 2 and 1. but my query result prints '3'. How to use or condition in Laravel query?

```
Role table
  user_id role_id 
   210     2
   210     1

    $user_role=role_mapping::where('user_id','=',210)
    ->where('role_id','=','2')
    ->orwhere('role_id','=','3')
    ->select('role_mapping.role_id')->first();

     echo $user_role->role_id;  // print 3
```

Comment: Try this `$user_role=role_mapping::where('user_id','=',210)->Where(function ($query) {
                $query->where('role_id','=','2') ->orWhere('role_id','=','3');
            })->select('role_mapping.role_id')->first();` :)

Comment: @MARABOC caught syntax error, unexpected '{'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**AND** operator has higher priority than **OR** operator, so the query you're running is:

```
WHERE (user_id = 210 AND role_id = 2) OR role_id = 3
```

while you should be running

```
WHERE user_id = 210 AND (role_id = 2 OR role_id = 3)
```

The following will do the trick:

```
role_mapping::where('user_id','=',210)
  ->where(function($query) {
    $query->where('role_id','=','2')->orWhere('role_id','=','3');
  })
  ->select('role_mapping.role_id')->first();
```